# Choose a typeclass based on return type

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I want to be able to have a function, which implementation will choose a typeclass based on the manual type specification of it's return type.

Here's a contrived example: a typeclass and two instances:

```
class ToString a where
  toString :: a -> String

instance ToString Double where
  toString = const "double"

instance ToString Int where
  toString = const "int"
```

I'm able to choose the instance by calling the toString with `Int` type:

```
function :: String
function = toString (undefined :: Int)
```

So far so good. What I'd like to do is to be able to write the function, so it will work for any `a` if there exists a typeclass for it:

```
function' :: (ToString a) => String
function' = toString (undefined :: a)
```

Here, the `function'` doesn't compile, because the `a` type parameter is not mentioned anywhere in the signature and it's not possible to specify the typeclass upon calling.

So it looks like the only option is to pass the type information about the type of `a` into the return type:

```
data Wrapper a = Wrapper {
  field :: String }

function'' :: (ToString a) => Wrapper a
function'' = Wrapper $ toString (undefined :: a)

showToString :: String
showToString = field (function'' :: Wrapper Int)
```

I define a `Wrapper` type just for carrying the type information. In the `showToString`, my hope is that since I specify the exact type of `Wrapper`, then the typechecker can infer that the `a` in `function''` is and `Int` and pick the `Int` instance of the `ToString` typeclass.

But the reality doesn't correspond with my hopes, this is the message from compiler

> Could not deduce (ToString a0) arising from a use of `toString'

Is there a way, how to convince the compiler, that he can pick the right typeclass in the `function''`, because I specify the it by having the type declaration of `:: Wrapper Int`?

Comment: I guess you might need existential types or some such thing. I just want you to  note that in `function''` the type expression `undefined::a` could be written `undefined::b` without change in meaning, as type variables are not scoped (unless you turned the corresponding GHC extension on).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let me suggest that instead of an own `Wrapper` type, you use [`Data.Tagged.Tagged`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tagged-0.8.0.1/docs/Data-Tagged.html), whose purpose is exactly this kind of stuff.

Apart from that, you need to turn on the `-XScopedTypeVariables` extension, otherwise the `a` type variable only exists in the type signature itself, but not in signatures of local bindings.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.Tagged

function''' :: forall a. ToString a => Tagged a String
function''' = Tagged $ toString (undefined :: a)
```

The explicit `forall` is necessary for `a` to actually become a scoped variable, otherwise the extension doesn't kick in.

### However....

Actually, the best thing would probably to have the class method produce a tagged value in the first place:

```
class NamedType a where
  typeName :: Tagged a String

instance NamedType Double where
  typeName = Tagged "double"
instance NamedType Int where
  typeName = Tagged "int"
...
```

Or don't write your own class at all but use [typeable](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html):

```
import Data.Typeable

typeName' :: Typeable a => Tagged a String
typeName' = fmap show $ unproxy typeRep
```

Of course, that will give you the actual uppercase type names, and it might work for types you don't actually want it to.

Comment: Wow, it's pretty surprising that `show @TyCon = tyConName`. I'd have expected something more like `show tc = tyConPackage tc ++ "-" ++ tyConModule tc ++ "." ++ tyConName`. I wonder how that decision was made, way back when.

Answer (score 2):

leftaroundabout's answer is probably the one you want. But for completeness, here's one more thing you can do:

```
unwrap :: Wrapper a -> a
unwrap = error "can't actually unwrap"

function'' :: (ToString a) => Wrapper a
function'' = x
  where
    x = Wrapper (toString (unwrap x))
```

The idea is that I want an `a` to pass to `toString` but only `Wrapper a` shows up in my type. So I just define a function which takes `Wrapper a` and produces `a` – such a function can't have a real implementation, but we're not using it for its return value anyway – and apply it to the `Wrapper a` thing.

There's a bit of additional awkwardness because `Wrapper a` shows up in the *result* instead of an argument, but this (slightly silly) recursion takes care of that.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth mentioning that the existing answers are obsolete by now, because GHC has now better mechanisms for doing this. Basically, the original

```
function' :: (ToString a) => String
```

from the question is *just fine* now, provided you turn on `-XAllowAmbiguousTypes`. You still need scoped type variables to implement it, thus:

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes, ScopedTypeVariables, UnicodeSyntax #-}

function' :: ∀ a . ToString a => String
function' = toString (undefined :: a)
```

This gets even easier if, as I also suggested earlier, you just use that in the class right away:

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}

class NamedType a where
  typeName :: String

instance NamedType Double where
  typeName = "double"

instance NamedType Int where
  typeName = "int"
```

The caveat with both versions is that you need special syntax to select what instance is meant in a given use case. But that's easy:

```
ghci> :set -XTypeApplications
ghci> typeName @Double
"double"
ghci> typeName @Int
"int"
```

Comment: OK, but how do you type ∀ in vim or whatever?

Comment: [`C-k F A`](https://vimhelp.org/digraph.txt.html#digraphs-define)

Comment: I don't know how to remember such things, but thanks.